# How can I specify a margin as a percentage?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, margin, styling

I have just started using WPF. I'm getting my head around styling system since. I come from a CSS background and I would like to set margin in percentage.

```
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="workflowNameTextBlock">            
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="50"/>            
    </Style>
```

Currently value is set in pixels, but I would like to set it in %, i.e. 50%.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's how you implement 20% left and right margins in WPF:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Hello, world."/>
</Grid>
```

This may seem ridiculously verbose if what you're trying to do is re-implement a simple CSS layout in WPF, but that's because implementing simple CSS layouts is really not the problem space WPF is designed around.

Comment: Could we use Margin="2*,6*,2*,5*" as well?

Comment: Afaik, the star sizing only works in grid column and row definitions. It seems like overkill, but the grid with star sized rows and columns is the way to do this in XAML.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using Margin, you can do this via a Grid.

Just place your control within a Grid element, and use 3 columns and 3 rows.  The column/row sizing can be done as percentages of the containing element.

Comment: Yes. Here is the link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/dealing-with-percentage-size-in-wpf/