# XAML Fluid layout of Metro application

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF - Margin in percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907880/wpf-margin-in-percentage)

I programming simple Metro application using C# and XAML.
I have image background and background image is filled whole screen - for resolution independency.
But now, I wanna place some buttons and they are positioned using margin. But this solution is not resolution independency.

Is there any way how to place elements with resolution independency? Something like percentage margin in CSS?

Thank for your help.

Comment: You should post the XAML code, at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use star column widths and column heights in Grid.ColumnDefinitions/RowDefinitions, so you would do it like that:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition
            Width="5*" />
        <ColumnDefinition
            Width="4*" />
        <ColumnDefinition /> <!-- 1* is the default -->
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock
        Text="Percentage aligned text in column 0 (default)" />
    <TextBlock
        Text="Percentage aligned text in column 2"
        Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

The alternative is to design it to specific width/height and put it inside of a Viewbox control which will stretch it to the dimensions available.

*EDIT

I wrote a blog post on layout that might help you too.

http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2012/10/13/layout-and-formatting-with-windows-8-xaml-development/